# kableExtra collapse_rows valign argument not aligning and second group level not grouped

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

The following code does not produce vertically aligned values in column 1, and does not group the value of column 2 at all. What am I doing wrong? I updated `kableExtra` and tried changing the order of the arguments to `collapse_rows`.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

collapse_rows_dt <- data.frame(C1 = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 5)),
                           C2 = c(rep("c", 7), rep("d", 3), rep("c", 2), rep("d", 3)),
                           C3 = 1:15,
                           C4 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE))
collapse_rows_dt <- collapse_rows_dt[-11, ]
kable(collapse_rows_dt, "latex", align = "c") %>%
kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1:2,
            latex_hline = "major",
            valign      = "middle",
            row_group_label_position = 'stack',
            row_group_label_fonts = list(list(bold = T), list(bold = T)))`
```

Should look similar to table top of [page 17](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf):

[image]

actual output:

[image]

Comment: What do you want it to look like in the end? A sketch or display of the first few lines would be helpful to understand. Thanks :)